# R package installs correctly, but functions do not work

Tags: r, function, installation, package

I've been recently trying to develop my own R package. I therefore installed Rtools and all seemed to be fine, the package installed and loaded, and the documentation was created without errors. However, if any of the functions in the package was called, a "could not find function" error was returned.

Seeing some previous question on Stack Overflow, some answers pointed out issues with dependencies, others talked about function names containing dots. But not even the following example will work:

Given a "path" in out local machine, we execute the following R code:

```
library("devtools")
library("roxygen2") #No docs will be generated, so maybe this is not needed.
setwd("path")
create("my_package")
```

Now we write a file named "trivial_function.R", containing the following

```
trivial_function <- function(x,y) {
  return(x*y)
}
```

We move "trivial_function.R" into path/my_package/R

Here I think this step is not needed, but in previous attempts I executed:

```
setwd("my_package")
document()
```

And finally:

```
setwd("path")
check("my_package")
install("my_package")
library("my_package")
trivial_function(2,3)
```

Returning the following error message: 
Error in trivial_function(2, 3) : could not find function "trivial_function"

Thank you for your attention! Any ideas?

Comment: You need to put the function in the namespace. You can create "NAMESPACE" file in the root directory. `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` will export all functions with alphabetic names. The easiest way would be using Rstudio's prototype, moving your R-codes to `R/` and modifying   "DESCRIPTION" and "NAMESPACE" files as you need.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelly I cannot put it to work. If I add exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+") to NAMESPACE before installation, the file gets overwritten. If I add it afterwards on the "lib" folder, it has no effect

Comment: My hunch is you have some setting where you execute roxygen2, which auto-generate the NAMESPACE file. You can add roxygen note for the function. See https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/docs.html

Comment: Yes. That's right! The NAMESPACE file is generated by Roxygen2 algonside the documentation. Indeed, two diffferent versions of it are made! One after create(), which contains "exportPattern("^[^\\.]")" and the other after document(), which does not. The result is the same with any of them though

Comment: I've finally found a way to install the package properly, however it's only by means of not using any documentation at all